# What is liberated both ways?

Tags: liberation

“liberated both ways” can you tell me what does it mean? I will find the discourse later

Answer (score 5):

In theory, according to Pali Canon, you can attain Enlightenment either through understanding or through meditation. "Liberated both ways" is one who got it both ways.

In practice, every teacher worth his or her salt will tell you that intellectual study without meditation is fooling oneself, and at the same time sitting in meditation until your butt falls off is complete waste of time if you don't have understanding. And both are useless if you don't integrate it with real life.

So in practice, Liberated Both Ways is the only option.

Comment: and I guess what you call complete waste of time. is also fruitful after many decades. i.e some one will eventually understand just by sitting for long hours for many decade. and also some one who understand it all will eventually sit and do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Sujato's final footnote for [DN 15](https://suttacentral.net/dn15/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin) says:

> Here we see the terms “one who is freed” used in two ways. All
> arahants have “freedom of heart” (by means of samādhi) and “freedom by
> wisdom” (the realization of the Dhamma). At the same time, one who
> emphasizes samādhi is said to have “freedom of heart” in contrast with
> one who emphasizes wisdom, who has “freedom by wisdom”. One who has
> consummate mastery of both samādhi and wisdom is said to be “freed
> both ways”.

If we read the end of [DN 15](https://suttacentral.net/dn15/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin), the Eight Liberations (which collectively are one of the 'both/two' liberations) particularly emphasise the Immaterial/Formless Spheres. Therefore, "Liberated Both Ways" here (in [DN 15](https://suttacentral.net/dn15/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin)) can be contrasted with [SN 12.70](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.70/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin), where the monks declare Arahantship without attainment of the Immaterial/Formless Spheres.

> “Well, knowing and seeing thus, do you have direct meditative
> experience of the peaceful liberations that are formless, transcending
> form?”
>
> “No, reverend.”
>
> “Well now, venerables, how could there be such a declaration when
> these things are not attained?”
>
> “Reverend Susīma, we are freed by wisdom.”
>
> [SN 12.70](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.70/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin)

Note: the Arahant monks in [SN 12.70](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.70/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin) have attained the Four Jhana of the Noble Eightfold Path; but have not attained the Four Immaterial/Formless Spheres.

Answer (score 2):

short answer: An arahant who has not only 4 jhānas, but also formless attainments.
An arahant who is only wisdom liberated (pañña vimutti) only has 4 jhānas.

comprehensive answer:
summary of all the sutta passages (10) and links to those suttas that use the term 'liberated both ways'
https://notesonthedhamma.blogspot.com/2024/02/ubhato-bhaga-vimutta-liberated-both.html

Comment: reading that blog: i think "placing the mind and keeping it connected" is a good way to describe vitarka-vichara

Comment: https://lucid24.org/sted/8aam/8samadhi/vitakka/index.html

Comment: in an oral tradition, vitakka and vicara has to be linguistc verbal thought. "placing and connecting the mind" happens in all 4 jhanas and first 7 attainemnets, it can't drop out after first jhana, among many other reasons that translation is horrendously wrong

Comment: the pali is quite consistent about vitarka-vichara dropping out after the first jhana..perhaps it has served its purpose ie cittekaggata